# Swap Show/Hide Behaviors for Multiple Elements Individually

Tags: jquery

I've read previous questions asked about using jQuery to show/hide multiple elements individually, but I haven't been able to modify the code that worked for those users so that it works for my case.

Here's the breakdown:

- Page will have multiple blog posts
- Each blog post will have default behavior of showing Post Excerpt with a "Show More" link
- When the "Show More" link of a single post is clicked, the Post Excerpt should be hidden and the Full Post content should appear with a "Show Less" link at the bottom (should only occur on single post instance, so I've setup my code to include a custom ID but maybe I placed it in the wrong spot?)
- When the "Show Less" link of a single post is clicked, the Full Post content should be hidden and the Post Excerpt should reappear with the "Show More" link at the bottom (again, should only occur on single post instance, not affect all posts at the same time)

The problem: 
The actual result from the code below ends up doing the following:

- Swaps the Post Excerpt for the Full Content, as expected, when the "Show More" link is clicked
- Does NOT swap the Full Content for the Post Excerpt when the "Show Less" link is clicked

Any idea why? I'm not great with jQuery; I tend to learn code best when I hack around with existing code examples, so I'm still struggling to understand what's happening to cause this behavior instead of the expected behavior.

The actual HTML of the post index uses a lot of CMS template-specific code that may not make sense if I include it, so I've replaced it with the bare minimum of what the generated content would look like. I've added the jQuery and HTML I've setup for my testing purposes below...

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#full-3434').hide();
      $('.show-more').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#excerpt-' + id).hide(); 
        $('#full-' + id).show();
     });
      $('.show-less').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#full-' + id).hide(); 
        $('#excerpt-' + id).show();
     });
    });
    </script>

<div class="entry-body">
    <div class="excerpt" id="excerpt-3434">
        <p>Post Excerpt Here. This will disappear when the "Show More" 
        link is clicked and the Full Post Content will display instead.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="show-more" id="3434">Show More</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="full" id="full-3434">
        <p>Full Post Content Here. This will be hidden by default. When 
        the "Show Less" link is clicked, the Full Post Content will 
        disappear and Post Excerpt will reappear.</p>

        <p><a href="#" class="show-less" id="3434">Show Less</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any and all help appreciated! :D

Comment: Your code, copied and pasted works fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czarchaic/aHC6b/)

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me in my testing, but when there were multiple instances, each with a unique ID, it would stop. I was given a working solution below, but I appreciate your taking the time to test it out for me! :)

Answer (score 2):

One of basic things in HTML is: you should only have one element with the same id.

The solution of problem of yours may be having this html:

```
<div id="3434" class="entry-body">
<div class="excerpt">
    <p>Post Excerpt Here. This will disappear when the "Show More" 
    link is clicked and the Full Post Content will display instead.</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="show-more">Show More</a></p>
</div>

<div class="full">
    <p>Full Post Content Here. This will be hidden by default. When 
    the "Show Less" link is clicked, the Full Post Content will 
    disappear and Post Excerpt will reappear.</p>

    <p><a href="#" class="show-less">Show Less</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

and this body of the function

```
 $('#3434 .full').hide();
  $('.show-more').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('.entry-body').attr('id');
    $('#' + id + ' .excerpt').hide(); 
    $('#' + id + ' .full').show();
 });
  $('.show-less').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('.entry-body').attr('id');
    $('#' + id + ' .full').hide(); 
    $('#' + id + ' .excerpt').show();
 });
```

But this is still clumsy. You can take even more power from css and with this style:

```
.entry-body .more .full, .entry-body .less .excerpt { display: block }
.entry-body .more .excerpt, .entry-body .less .full { display: none }
```

you can have this body of a function:

```
 $('#3434').addClass('less');
  $('.show-more').click(function () {
        var post = $(this).closest('.entry-body');
    post.removeClass('less'); 
    post.addClass('more');
 });
  $('.show-less').click(function () {
        var post = $(this).closest('.entry-body');
    post.removeClass('more'); 
    post.addClass('less');
 });
```

This does all the changes by simply swapping classes and let you do lot more changes between two states of a post in css, not just "shown" / "hidden".

EDIT:

And if you swap `$('#3434').addClass('less')` with `$('.entry-body').addClass('less')` you have nice general self-contained code that does not use any ugly id whatsoever and works for any number of posts on the page.

Comment: I'll have to try this out in a little bit. Thanks for taking the time to respond in depth, Herby!

Comment: It worked beautifully, Herby! Thanks so much for all of your help. :) I was also able to smoothly insert some additional functions to .show-less when clicked, but I wouldn't have been able to do that without your initial help.

Comment: See EDIT on bottom of the answer.

Comment: Does my answer lacks something or is it satisfying (so you can vote it and select it)?